# Entity framework 6 + network

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following DB Model
[image]

At home I work with Visual Studio and SQL-Server on my PC. Now I took the PC at work and tried to create an EFModel using a SQL-Server in our network.
Creating the Model at work I get 44 Errors.
First curious thing (for me) is i get a msgbox with "Running this text template can potentially harm your computer.Do not run it , if u obtained it from an untrusted source..." i confirmed with ok (two times for 2 pop ups). Afterwards I see 44 Errors. After a few minutes I get the same msgbox as above again. After pressing OK a few errors are deleted (now I have 32 Errors).

Since I have the german express version I try to translate the remaining errors by structure:

- `"Public Property WindesName as String" has many definitions with identical signatures.`
- `variable "_WindowsName" creates a conflict with a property "WindowsName" that is an implicitly declared member of class "Name"`

I have this kind of errors for every field.

What I tried: I actually wanted to create the Model into a program, that doesnt work. Then i used a blank application, doesent work too. I reinstalled EF from nuget with no effect.

Maybe it has something to do with the model or with the network. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to fix it. I changed Code Generation Strategy to Standard, deleted the two .tt files and rebuild the project. Now it is working.

Comment: My Code Generation Strategy is *T4* instead of *Standard*. But it is readonly. How can we change it into *Standard*?